# SKSpriteNode Not Showing

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, skscene

so i have this code:

```swift
func addSprites() {
    for row in 0..<GameScene.rows {
      for col in 0..<GameScene.cols {
        let node = grid[row][col]
        if node != nil {
          addChild(node!)
          node?.position = CGPoint(x: (view!.frame.width/CGFloat(GameScene.cols))*CGFloat(col), y: (view!.frame.height/CGFloat(GameScene.rows))*CGFloat(row))
          print(node?.position)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and the grid array has SKSpriteNodes and when i print it this shows

[image]

which is fine since i have `SKSpriteNode`'s in it.

The `addSprites()` outputs

```swift
Optional((0.0, 207.0))
Optional((59.733333587646484, 207.0))
Optional((119.46666717529297, 207.0))
Optional((179.1999969482422, 207.0))
Optional((238.93333435058594, 207.0))
Optional((298.6666564941406, 207.0))
Optional((358.3999938964844, 207.0))
Optional((418.1333312988281, 207.0))
Optional((477.8666687011719, 207.0))
Optional((537.5999755859375, 207.0))
Optional((597.3333129882812, 207.0))
Optional((657.066650390625, 207.0))
Optional((716.7999877929688, 207.0))
Optional((776.5333251953125, 207.0))
Optional((836.2666625976562, 207.0))
```

which is corresponding to the node's location.However as seen here no sprites show:

[image]

when I print the touch location in the `touchesBegan` method and saw the points, even though the points were exactly the same, the sprites don't show. How can I fix this? Also i tried `scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill` in the `GameViewController`, however that didn't fix it.

Comment: What sprite?  I don't see one in your code, either.

Comment: @ElTomato the sprite is in the grid array, all of their positions are printed

Comment: @ElTomato also the grid has been printed out

Comment: I also see the word node a few times.  I don't know what it is.  And I don't know how you create it.

Comment: @ElTomato `let node = grid[row][col]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, however I'm not sure why it works, but I changed the anchor point to (0,0) and all of the sprites show!!